# Which places in the Bible have been suggested in Christianity as a basis for the possibility that some of humans before Christ could be saved?

Tags: soteriology

Which places in the Bible have been suggested in Christianity as a possible basis for the possibility that some of humans who were not Jews and lived before Christ still could be saved?

The [wiki page on Salvation in Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvation_in_Christianity#Old_Testament) focuses more on different beliefs about salvation that are existing in Christianity, but doesn't cite much of the basis from the Bible for that particular point that I am asking about.

Comment: The whole book of Job is an explanation of how Job, not a Jew, was saved. I don't understand the need for your question.

Comment: In lieu of a full answer, I think [this article](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/1475-did-the-ancient-gentiles-have-the-hope-of-salvation) comprehensively covers the theological reason as well as OT biblical evidence for God's saving plan for the Gentiles even before Christ.  Don't forget that Adam, Eve, Abel, Noah, Enoch, Job, Melchizedek, etc. were not Israelites.

Comment: @NigelJ - Thank you, Nigel. Very good point about Job!

Comment: @GratefulDisciple - Thank you for that link and also for pointing out the cases of Adam, Eve, Abel, Noah, Enoch, Job and Melchizedek!

Comment: @brilliant You're welcome. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

- In Genesis: **Enoch** (who was carried into heaven without dying) and Noah.
- In Job: Job. **Job** declared his faith that even if he died, in his flesh he would see God. In Job 42, God endorsed Job's statements about him.
- In Judges: **Rahab**, a prostitute of Jericho.
- In Ruth: **Ruth**, a Moabite, became an ancestor or King David of Israel.
- In 1 Kings: The **Widow of Zarephath** (and her son, whom Elijah raised from the dead). She was a resident of Sidon, not Israel.
- In 2 Kings: **Naaman**, a senior Syrian official, is healed by Elisha, then declares his faith in the God of Israel.

Comment: In some Christian denominations both Enoch and Elijah are in the Earthly Paradise awaiting to return as the Two Witnesses of Revelation. Thus heavens can be interpreted as sky.

Comment: @KenGraham - That is one of the beliefs I consider a strong possibility. I also think that the two witnesses are the church and Israel, which will each be persecuted during the tribulation. Both could be true, with Elijah leading the remnant of Israel and Enoch leading the remnant of the church.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but... how do we know that the Widow of Zarephath got saved? Instead of "who were not Jews" in my question I should have said "were not part of Jewish faith" to be more precise. So, I am afraid, only the first two examples in your answer fit the bill.

Comment: According to Jesus, the Widow was not Jewish. As for whether we know if she was saved, your question was about people who have been suggested as meeting your criteria, which they have. We have evidence, not proof.

Comment: @PaulChernoch - You are right. Thank you.